# Abdominal; Why isn't it 'abdomenal' (with an 'e'), and is there a name for such words?

Tags: adjectives, latin

Why is the word 'abdominal' formed of an altered spelling of 'abdomen'? I have noticed other words similar, but none spring to mind; is there a name for them?

Answer (score 2):

I appears it is because of its etymology, from the genitive of abdomen, (and the French *abdominal*), [abdominal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abdominalis&searchmode=none):

> - 1550s, from medical Latin abdominalis, from abdomen (genitive abdominis).

(etymonline)

Comment: The real question is why "abdomen" is not "abdomin".

Comment: Surely, @HotLicks , if Josh is right and the word is abdomen in Latin in some nominative or accusative case but abdominis in the genitive (I don't know the language myself), then it makes perfect sense that our noun take the nom/acc form and adjective the gen?

Comment: @DanSheppard - I think abdominis  entered the French language  first, then became part of the English language. French/Spanish,  *abdomen - abdominal*. Italian,  *addome - addominali*. Same process for all languages that adoped the term.